# Android show progeress bar

Tags: android

Hello i have such problem. I have a `ListView` on click i need to do a background task, so i need to show `ProgressBar`. So i do smth like that

```
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FutureTask<City> task = new FutureTask<City>(new getWeather(city));
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(task);
        City city1 = null;
        try{
            city1 = task.get();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        //City city1 = City.getInstance(city);
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and my Task :

```
public class getWeather implements Callable<City> {
    String city;
    public getWeather(String c) {
        city = c;
    }
    @Override
    public City call() throws Exception {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        City city1 = new City();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(City.CITY, city);
        city1.setArguments(bundle);
        return city1;
    }
}
```

But my UI doesn't change i see this: `09-29 11:20:10.455  29977-29977/com.example.mike.myapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

How i can fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use `ProgressDiaolg` instead of `ProgressBar` for this kind of task. And it would be better to show the progress dialog in AsyncTask's `onPreExecute` and dismiss in `onPostExecute`

Code snippet:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog 
//in onPreExecute
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Updating data.. Please wait");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();

//After updating the data in onPostExecute
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting the Log: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` which means you are trying to change the progress of the progressbar on the main thread, try using `Async Task`

```
private class someAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //your code task here

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    if (progressBar != null) {
        //update progressbar here
    }
}
```

}

To start the progrress bar async task:

```
ProgressBarAsyncTask pbTask = new ProgressBarAsyncTask();
pbTask.execute();
```

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/) and this [tutorial](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/06/basic-asynctask-with-progress-bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

onCreateMethod

new LongOperation().execute();

```
 private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
 {

     private String Content;
     private String Error = null;
     private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MG02DataSynchronize1.this);
     protected void onPreExecute() {

         Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
         Dialog.show();

     }
      // Call after onPreExecute method
     protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {



     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

         // Close progress dialog
         Dialog.dismiss();



 }
```